# How can I plot two parts of Möbius strip bonding together?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

How can I plot two parts of Möbius strip bonding together like the following picture?[image]

The parametric equations:

```
x[u_, v_] := (2 + v Sin[u/2]) Cos[u]
y[u_, v_] := (2 + v Sin[u/2]) Sin[u]
z[u_, v_] := v Cos[u/2]
```

I take the plots

```
m1 = ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}, {u, \[Pi]/3, 
   5 \[Pi]/3 }, {v, -1/2, 1/2}, Boxed -> False, 
   PlotPoints -> {150, 150}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
   PlotStyle -> LightBlue]
m2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}, {u, 4 \[Pi]/3, 
    8 \[Pi]/3 }, {v, -1/2, 1/2}, Boxed -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> {150, 150}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
   PlotStyle -> Red]

 Show [m1, m2]
```

I tried this one, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Sticking as close as possible to what you wrote:

```
x[u_, v_] = (2 + v Sin[u/2]) Cos[u];
y[u_, v_] = (2 + v Sin[u/2]) Sin[u];
z[u_, v_] = v Cos[u/2];

m1 = ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}, {u, π/3, 5π/3}, {v, -1/2, 1/2},
  Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> {150, 150}, Mesh -> None,
  PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Opacity[.5]}]

m2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}, {u, 4π/3, 8π/3}, {v, -1/2, 1/2},
  Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> {150, 150}, Mesh -> None,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Opacity[.5]}]

Show[m1, m2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: PlotRange -> All  That just is my need !  Thanks !

Comment: The other thing I changed was the two separate PlotStyle commands that need to be merged into one.

Answer (score 1):

```
moebiusstrip[a_][u_, v_] := {a Cos[u] + v Cos[u/2] Cos[u], 
     a Sin[u] + v Cos[u/2] Sin[u], v Sin[u/2]}

mss := moebiusstrip[2]

a := .6
z1 = ParametricPlot3D[mss[u, v], {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, -a, a},
     PlotPoints -> {24, 8}]
```

[image]

Comment: Not  the Möbius strip itself ,but the two distinct parts of  Möbius strip  bonding together (In my post's picture , left part of  Möbius strip and  right part of  Möbius strip bound together overlapping A and B, and then the bouned two parts make up the  whole  Möbius strip ).Thanks all the same.